# website update delay (doesn't update when saving)

Tags: html, css, delay

I'm a newbie working on a one page website. I experiment a lot with code - paste a bit of this, a bit of that in the html/css file, check if it works, keep it or delete it.

I realized that sometimes, when I decide to delete the code (just going back a step and saving), instead of coming back to the previous state, the website goes wild.

For example:

I pasted some responsive gallery code, among it:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

decided I don't like it - clicked "step backwards" and saved. What I see now:

- another responsive gallery went nuts (huge images)
- navbar changed its background color - I made that change long time ago, it didn't work and I forgot to delete it. For some reason it decided to change NOW.

I don't understand this behaviour, as theoreticaly the website should come back to the previous state, shouldn't it?

EDIT: I don't have enough reputation here on Stackoverflow to answer my own question, so I'll write here: I tried clearing cookies, but no effect. Any other ideas? Thnx for answering anyway!

Answer (score 1):

that is because of the browser. Your browser store all the information in th COOKIES. if you cleared the cookies and see again you can see the updated page. You just have to clear the cookies of the browser which you are using.

Comment: Hi Atal, sorry for the late answer - as it turned out, it was a bunch of problems one on top of another, but it works now. Anyway, I'm voting for your answer as I know most of the time it's about the cookies. Thnx!